# How can i show and hide TextBox based on DropDownList selection in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

When the Custmor item (option) is selected in the DropDownList, TextBox named (why) will be visible else the TextBox will be hidden in ASP.Net Core
When an Custmor item (option) is selected in the DropDownList, the Text box is visible How can i change it to invisible ?
enter code here

















custmor
account

```
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Axe" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="Axe" class="form-control">
                <option>géographique</option>
                <option>démographique</option>
                <option>psycologique</option>
                <option>comportementale</option>

            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="me">
            <label asp-for="why" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="why class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="why" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

i tried this script and doesn't work

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>


<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#show").click(function () {
            $("#me").show();
            $("#he").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to show and hide the div based on the selected option, if so, you can use the change function and change the script like below:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#show").change(function () {
            var option = $(this).val();
            if (option == "xxx") { 
                $("#me").show();
            } else {
                $("#me").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @manelsayari, if my reply is helpful, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), thanks!